# How do I return my large Google BigQuery v2 response?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have tried to run a simple query, but I get the error `response too large to return`

> SELECT accno, year, month,  count(*) as cnt
>   FROM eric.accesslogs_tbl
>   GROUP BY accno, year, month
>   ORDER BY cnt, year, month limit 1000;

My data table statistics:

> Table Size:    64.7 GB
>   Number of Rows: 59,971,371

Is there a workaround for it? Otherwise, we can't use it.

Comment: How many rows is the query trying to return?

Answer (score 2):

The limit you're hitting is not the number of rows you can return, the limit is the amount of data internally used by a `GROUP BY` operation.

There is an experimental feature that will let you remove this limitation: try using `GROUP EACH BY` instead of `GROUP BY`.

Alternately you could do this without using experimental features using the `TOP` [function](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#top-function). Your case makes `TOP` a little bit trickier since you want the top results for three different fields, but you can concatenate them together:

```
SELECT TOP(acct_month, 1000), COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(
        STRING(accno), '-'), STRING(year)), '-'), STRING(month)) 
        AS acct_month 
    FROM eric.accesslogs_tbl)
```

The results will be a little bit wonky, since they'll have a single field accno-year-month.